# JS / CSS - How to match element containing string

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am working with an HTML file that is generated by an old system, so I am not in control of the HTML code generation, unfortunately.

The HTML code looks like the below:

```html
<table cellpadding=10>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: XYZ</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: XYZ</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: 123</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: XYZ</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: XYZ</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The table contains 1 row for the Table Header, and then 4 rows of data.
As you can see, the first cell of the third row of data has a different text `Name: 123`.

I need to hide/remove the row `Name: 123`.

So far I've tried using CSS, but there is no selector that will allow me to match an element that contains a given `String`.

**How can I hide/remove the row `Name: 123`? I'm happy to use CSS or JS if need be.**

Comment: Loop through the rows. and test if the first cell's `innerText` equals `Name: 123`. If it does, use CSS to hide the row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick up a node list of all the first child elements (i.e. the first cell) of each row, and iterate over them. If its text content matches "Name: 123" then remove its parent node (the row element) from the DOM.

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('tr td:first-child');

for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  if (cells[i].textContent === 'Name: 123') {
    cells[i].parentNode.classList.add('hidden');
    break;
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<table cellpadding=10>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: XYZ</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: XYZ</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: 123</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: XYZ</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: XYZ</td>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum Description</td>
    <td>More Lorem Ipsum</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy. This is brilliant!  Would it be possible to use JS to find the `tr` element, and then use CSS to hide it? I think it would be rather safer for me to add a class to hide the `tr` instead of removing the content altogether  :/

Comment: @Adriano I added a "hidden class" that you can add to the parent. See the edit. It just sets its display to `none`.